# Get random value in the range of plus/minus 10% of a cell value in Excel

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I have a column with positive numbers and want to calculate for each of them a random value, which is however placed in the range of 10%, so the calculated value is maximally 10% lower or higher as the original value.

The second requirement is - the result must be higher then zero.

I tried a formula like the following - but it seems to be wrong, because of not matching the second requirement, i get sometimes values lower then zero.

`=IF(RAND()<0.5,(B2+(B2/100)*90)-(RANDBETWEEN(B2-0.1,B2+0.1)),(B2-(B2/100)*90)+(RANDBETWEEN(B2-0.1,B2+0.1)))`

Comment: Surely any positive number minus 10% or plus 10% will still be positive?

Comment: @JvdV they should, indeed:) Its just a sign of my wrong formula, not a new math law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only dealing with integers and your value is in `B2`, why not just use `RANDBETWEEN(B2*0.9, B2*1.1)`. If `B2` is positive, this cannot return a negative number since 0.9 * a positive number will still be positive.

If you want to have floating point numbers, you can use `RAND()` to generate a random number between 0 and 1, then subtract 0.5 and divide by 5 to get a number between -0.1 and 0.1. Then you can add 1 and multiply that by the original value to get something between 0.9 and 1.1 times it:

```
=(1+(RAND()-0.5)/5)*B2
```